# Copying Multiple columns in Excel-Vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to copy multiple columns from one workbook to another, and below is the code how I copied one and need help in making the code more optimized as I don't want to write same code for all the columns. below is the code.

```
Sub Copymc()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test2.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test1.xlsx")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

' determine where the data ends on Column B Sheet1

x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row

' copy the data from Column B in Sheet 1

Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy

' Determine where to add the new data in Column C Sheet 2

y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
NextRow = ActiveCell.Row

' paste the data to Column C Sheet 2

y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & NextRow).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

I tried to put all columns in range statement but problem I found was how to paste? How can I do it for multiple columns without repeating the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to copy columns A-D:

```
Sub Copymc()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test2.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test1.xlsx")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

' determine where the data ends on Column B Sheet1

x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row

' copy the data from Column B in Sheet 1

Range("A2:D" & LastRow).Copy y.worksheets("Sheet1").range("a65536").end(xlup).offset(1,0)

' Determine where to add the new data in Column C Sheet 2

'y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Range("A65536").Select
'ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
'NextRow = ActiveCell.Row

' paste the data to Column C Sheet 2

'y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & NextRow).Select

'ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid the copy and paste functions as much as possible. To get around this I would loop through all of the values in the column and move them to your other workbook as such:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test2.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test1.xlsx")
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    CopyVal = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
    CopyVal2 = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Value
    CopyVal3 = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Value
    CopyVal4 = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value

    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3).Value = CopyVal4
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Value = CopyVal3
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Value = CopyVal2
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = CopyVal

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited this to do multiple columns, I didn't see where you wanted multiple columns to move over. You could also create another variable and loop for however many columns you need.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would avoid a built in function (copy/paste) to write a much slower loop to do the same thing.

Comment: I need to check the speed on this, to my knowledge I didn't think it was much slower though. As to why, I learned over the years to avoid the clipboard, and again as far as I knew this was the best way to do that.

Comment: I, on the other hand, have learned over the years to not reinvent the wheel. Though I do see your point about the clipboard...

Comment: In testing it would appear you are correct, doing the copy with paste destinations as is shown in the other answer is quicker. 

So many things I need to reconsider now ;)

Comment: :) I was taught that the built ins were always faster (since they're not written in VBA, and they're compiled) than executing loops of interpreted VBA. However, your point about avoiding the clipboard is legit, since something else could, possibly, be stuffed into the clipboard right at the moment you need it. My rough estimate is that it's a non-zero chance, but probably not big enough to be a significant concern.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something new. I should say that on a moderate sample size of 4 columns and 1000 rows the copy method was 500 times faster, that benefit may outweigh a small chance of hitting an issue with the clipboard.

Comment: If the clipboard were a potential issue, couldn't you use `Application.CutCopyMode = False` before the copy/paste to clear the clipboard? Or does that only deselect a copied range in Excel?